# Jiffies not zero on boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

After reboot the jiffies are not initialized to zero, but instead to some high value (near the wrap-around).

For example (immediately after reboot):

```
cat /proc/timer_list | grep jiffies
    .idle_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .last_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .next_jiffies   : 4294902623
jiffies: 4294902561
    .idle_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .last_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .next_jiffies   : 4294902568
jiffies: 4294902561
    .idle_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .last_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .next_jiffies   : 4294902679
jiffies: 4294902561
    .idle_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .last_jiffies   : 4294902561
    .next_jiffies   : 4294902607
```

What am I missing? I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 3.13.0-36-generic. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there. You might do better if you asked this on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think it's deliberate. The `jiffies` value can wrap around fairly quickly; initializing it to a large value that will wrap shortly after boot discourages writing code that ignores wraparound.

Comment: It's supposed to be set to ~5 minutes to wraparound, see http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-2 and https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/akpm/patches/2.5/2.5.62/2.5.62-mm2/broken-out/initial-jiffies.patch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the boot jiffies is not initalized by zero, it is initalized by INITIAL_JIFFIES constant.

You can see this constant in linux kernel headers:

```
$ cd your_path_to_linux_kernel_headers
$ grep INITIAL_JIFFIES linux/jiffies.h
#define INITIAL_JIFFIES ((unsigned long)(unsigned int) (-300*HZ))
```

It was introduced by [this patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/akpm/patches/2.5/2.5.62/2.5.62-mm2/broken-out/initial-jiffies.patch) *to help detect problems related to that very overflow*.

Sorry for long waiting for answer. :)

Comment: The question has been answered in the comments long ago, but since you put the effort I will accept your answer.